# Создание ссылок на теги из полученного массива $term_id

Tags: wordpress

Был получен массив id тегов из которого необходимо сделать список рабочих ссылок, в котором URL будет ссылкой на тег и анкор будет названием тега.

Вот такой массив примерно я получаю (в данном случае возвращаться должно 3 id тега, но их может быть любое количество от нуля):

> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(2) "35" [2]=> string(2) "34" [3]=> string(2) "74" }

Как его обработать до состояния списка урлов?

Answer (score 0):

Перебираете массив, подставляете ID тега в такую структуру:

```
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term_id, $taxonomy ); ?>">Title</a>
```

на выходе получаете урлы

Comment: Не совсем понятно из вашего примера, как получить именно список с произвольным количеством переменных (я не знаю сколько тегов в массиве), и к тому же хотелось бы также получить и заголовки тегов, чтобы анкор не был "Title".